# How to extract partial text from an element seperated by <br> tag through selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

How to separate **70** from **70 (100%)** where 70 and (100%) are linked by `<br>` tag in selenium?

Here's the structure:

```
<a href="/report/campaigns/698/sent" class=""> 70<br> (100%)</a>
```

Code that I am using is :

```
String[] REP=new String[1];
String Repor= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html[1]/body[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[6]")).getText();

REP=Repor.split(""); 

System.out.println("REP "+REP[0]);
```

Output that i am getting is : 7

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: dhilmathy beat me to fixing it for you this time. Please do use the tools next time. Thanks!

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the HTML/DOM structure you're trying to get this information from.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link, not comments, to improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Xpath is crazy, but to address your issue I think it might be as simple as adding a space between the quotes in your split() function. It should be

```
REP=Repor.split(“ “)
```

Edit after clarification: the string Repor is being set with a line break.  Thus the following code should find "70" and "(100%)" individually.

```
String lines[] = Repor.split("\\r?\\n");
```

then `lines[0]` is "70" and `lines[1]` is "(100%)".  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Tried that already. Didn't work. Its printing the whole thing.

Comment: What does the string Repor come out to if you debug or add a print line just after it?

Comment: Prints the same whole thing. I am using it in a 'for loop' and getting values from a table column.

Comment: What, you mean including the br or just “70 %100”?

Comment: 70
(100%) This is the output for both cases.
 (100%) is in next line

Comment: I've edited my question to address the line break.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Yes. Got 70. But i need to store it as int and cant be using parseint since we have used string[]. kindly suggest.

Comment: Do you just want the first line, 70?  If so, the following should work: `result = int(lines[0])`

Comment: Yes i want only 70.  Used result = int(lines[0]) but following errors are thrown:
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
  String to int

Comment: Forgot we are using Java. Try Integer.parseInt(lines[0]);

Comment: @Ashu Have you gotten this to work?  If so would you accept one of mine or DebanjanB's answers if you get the chance?

Comment: Everything is working perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it.  On to the next problem!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text **70** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/report/campaigns/698/sent']"));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/report/campaigns/698/sent']"));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```

Comment: Tried the xpath locator strategy but the output came as 70 (100%). All in one line

Comment: Got the required result. Used substring method after your suggested code. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @Ashu Not sure where you are exactly stuck but if you have used my code you won't need `substring` for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Each tag is considered a separator for exist text-node of the parent tag: decision is to specify an index of desired text-node `//a/text()[1]`